# missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Consider the following schema:

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string) 
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string) 
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

The Catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by Suppliers.

I have two questions :

1. For every supplier that only supplies green parts, print the name of
   the supplier and the total number of parts that she supplies.
2. For every supplier that supplies a green part and a red part, print
   the name and price of the most expensive part that she supplies.

And here's what I've tried so far :

```
select  s.sname, count(*)
from    suppliers s, parts p, catalog c
where   p.pid = c.pid and c.sid = s.sid
group by s.sname, s.sid
having every (p.color = 'green')
```

and

```
select s.sname, max(c.cost)
from    suppliers s, parts p, catalog c
where   p.pid = c.pid and c.sid = s.sid
group by s.sname, s.sid
having some (p.color = 'green') and some (p.color = 'red')
```

When I am executing the above two queries the query output is showing missing right parenthesis need help thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `every` nor `some` in Oracle (at least, not in 11g), so none of your `having` clauses is correct.

Comment: it's not working when I am removing every or some and try with new text could you please help me by writing the entire query thankyou.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. If you could post some sample data and desired result, we'd be able to suggest how to do that.

Comment: Consider the following schema:
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
The Catalog relation lists the prices charged for parts by Suppliers.

Comment: sid sname address pid pname colour sid pid cost
----------------------- ---------------------- --------------
s1 smith london p1 nut red s1 p1 200
s2 jones paris p2 bolt green s1 p3 300
s3 blake paris p3 screw red s2 p1 100
s4 clark london p4 cam blue s2 p2 400
s5 adams athens p5 cog green s2 p3 200
s6 (you) regina s2 p4 300
 s2 p5 100
 s3 p2 200
 s3 p5 400
 s4 p4 400
 s5 p1 100
 s5 p2 200

Comment: For every supplier that only supplies green parts, print the name of the supplier and the total
number of parts that she supplies.

Comment: For every supplier that supplies a green part and a red part, print the name and
price of the most expensive part that she supplies.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but - this is unreadable. Please, edit the original question and put that information in there.

Comment: sid pid cost
 --------------
 s1 p1 200
 s1 p3 300
 s2 p1 100
 s2 p2 400
 s2 p3 200
 s2 p4 300
 s2 p5 100
 s3 p2 200
 s3 p5 400
 s4 p4 400
 s5 p1 100
 s5 p2 200

Comment: Yep, still unreadable. Please edit the question rather than posting code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can distinctly count green coloured parts :

```
select s.sname, count(distinct p.pid) as "Total #of Parts"
  from suppliers s
  join catalog c on c.sid = s.sid
  join parts p on p.pid = c.pid
 group by s.sname
having count(distinct case when p.color = 'green' then 1 end ) = 1
```

and for the second case you can consider at least one green, and at least one red coloured parts :

```
select s.sname, max(c.cost) as "Max Price"
  from suppliers s
  join catalog c on c.sid = s.sid
  join parts p on p.pid = c.pid
 group by s.sname
having count(case when p.color = 'green' then 1 end ) > 0
   and count(case when p.color = 'red' then 1 end ) > 0
```

`every` and `some` are invalid keywords within Oracle's SQL.

Comment: both the queries which you mentioned I am getting the error like ORA-00904: "C"."PID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"  when i am executing still hasn't solved need help.

Comment: excuse me I just needed to change the order of the join statements. Now, I fixed @prashanthchittompally